# Install ldap module with OSQA bitnami

Tags: python, django, bitnami, osqa, python-ldap

I am a beginner in Python, Django and OSQA

1. I installed OSQA (it works fine)

   with bitnami distribution on my computer (windows XP) http://bitnami.com/stack/osqa
2. I installed python-ldap (I can do import ldap)

   with  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ldap/
3. ???

Now I want to know what I should to be able to login via ldap on my OSQA. I could not find any clear tutorial about this. Can someone help me please ?